# Categorical variable as response in poisson regression

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, count-data, poisson-regression

I have data on damages on flowers from different treatments. The damage was originally count data (number of damages per flower) but the person collecting the data categorized the data in four levels - no damage (0) to a high damage level (3).

I know I could use logistic regression to model the odds but I wonder if it is possible to use poisson regression instead and consider the observed level of damage as a count variable?

If possible, would the intepretation of the dichotomized treatment coefficients be the difference in the logs of expected counts of damage levels for treatment compared to baseline while holding the other variables constant in the model?

The weird intepretation makes me think this is not at all possible.

Comment: I don't see how you can consider it a count. It won't have the properties of a count. Do you know how the recoding was done?

Comment: No you are absolutely correct, the variable is clearly bounded! Thank you.

Comment: Further, it won't have the variance = mean property that you see with a Poisson, for example.

Comment: Altough I guess that could be solved with negbin or quasipoisson?

Comment: Yes -- presuming we're happy about treating ordinal as interval then at least in some cases those should provide reasonable approximations - suitable for estimation of the mean, at least (but not necessarily suitable models for getting a prediction interval from, because of issues like the boundedness).

Comment: Also, for your first question: The recoding was done like this; 0 damages (0), 1-5 (1), 5-10 (2), 11-15 (3), no more levels were added as there were no need (no single case had more than 15 damages). Where the signs in the parantheses are the values assigned to the levels.

Comment: You *can* do inference about the underlying count variable on that basis, for example, via the E-M algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into this, do you have any resources on such inference to recommend?

Comment: Nothing both simple and directly related to your problem that comes to mind at the moment.

Comment: Anything just related would be fine! :)

Comment: Dempster has put up the original paper by Dempster, Laird and Rubin [here](http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~dsun/9720/EM_JRSSB.pdf); the wikipedia page on it isn't too terrible. There are numerous sets of notes and guides on line, as well as many questions here that discuss EM (try the search). There's [Bilmes' tutorial](http://crow.ee.washington.edu/people/bulyko/papers/em.pdf). But none of those quite fit what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Poisson random variable can take any integer value from 0 to $\infty$. If you fit a Poisson regression model to your data, you may get fitted values other than 0, 1, 2, 3. For this reason, I would not use a Poisson regression model.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. The idea was originally suggested to me from another fellow, I have also read Agresti (2013) and I am certain that it is not the correct method. I should have read it before asking the question! Thank you very much for taking the time to write your answer, the variable is clearly bounded.

Comment: What model would you recommend? The the response is clustered in blocks and I have one nominal predictor.

Comment: With only one predictor variable, I would do a simple multinomial regression. You can do this with the glm function in R with setting the family option equal to "multinomial".

Comment: Even with the clustering?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you don't know the clustering rule. So you are limited to modelling the categories.

Comment: The data comes from some experiment where experimental units were arrayed in blocks to reduce nuisance variation from external sources. Thus I know which units are in which clusters (the blocks).